# DDD Создание нескольких агрегатов в одной транзакции

Tags: c#, ddd, служба

**Ситуация:** Необходимо сгенерировать оборудование, например, бульдозер. Бульдозер является агрегатом и состоит из набора узлов (двигатель, кузов, колеса и т. д.). Каждый узел представляет собой отдельный агрегат со своим идентификатором.

Согласно книге Вон Вернона "Реализация методов предметно-ориентированного проектирования" стоит избегать изменения нескольких агрегатов в рамках одной транзакции.

В данном случае проще всего было бы в рамках одной транзакции создать сразу все узлы бульдозера, а потом создать сам бульдозер, хранящий ссылки на свои узлы.

**Уточнение:** Пример алгоритма метода генерации бульдозера, который можно реализовать в прикладной службе:

1. Создание экземпляра агрегата двигателя
2. Создание экземпляра агрегата кузова
3. Создание экземпляра агрегата колес
   ...
4. Формирование бульдозера.

**Вопрос:** допустимо ли такое нарушение рекомендации в рамках DDD? Если нет, то как лучше реализовать подобный сценарий?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://habrahabr.ru/post/316890/

Итак, кратко:

> Каждый агрегат может хранить ссылку как корни других агрегатов. При
>   этом это не помещает этот агрегат в границы согласованности первого
>   агрегата. Ссылка не порождает целостный агрегат.

И, то что вас интересовало:

> В рамках одной транзакции в ограниченном контексте должно происходить
>   изменение только одного агрегата.

Т.е. вы не должны менять агрегаты внутри других агрегатов. Создание, аналогично, должно происходить в разных транзакциях.

---

На случай, если не удалось завершить сборку бульдозера, можно просто удалять те части, которые уже были созданы, если они вам больше не нужны.

---

Отдельно - стоит помнить про согласованность агрегата.

> Если запрос клиента влияет на несколько агрегатов, необходимо
>   использовать принцип итоговой согласованности. Итоговую
>   согласованность можно достичь с помощью публикаций событий предметной
>   области. То есть, после изменения одного агрегата, он публикует
>   событие, и далее на одном или нескольких других агрегатах выполняются
>   действия, которые приводят к согласованности в системе.

Т.е. если изменение одного агрегата может сделать другой невалидным - вам надо обеспечить агрегатам возможность восстановить согласованное состояние.

---

Отдельно стоит подумать про вложенные транзакции. Они, в принципе, тоже могут вам помочь. Каждый вложенный агрегат создаете во вложенной транзакцией, а потом основной транзакцией сохраняете главный агрегат. Любая ошибка - откат всего.
Главный вопрос - а поддерживается ли вашей СУБД и ORM такая работа.

Comment: Главное чтобы в момент сборки не оказалось, что двигатель, который только что был создан, уже прикручен к другому бульдозеру - т.к. с точки зрения другого клиента это был лишний двигатель, который просто лежал на полке.

Comment: @PashaPash потенциальных проблем - море. Решений тоже можно сделать много. Сходу - можно сразу создавать двигатель с пометкой "занят", чтобы никто его не использовал. Можно обеспечить какое то временное хранилище, для тех, кто в процессе изменения\установки. А можно просто падать на создании бульдозера, если двигатель уже используется. DDD собственно особо не ограничивает в поведении, если меня не обманывает память.

Comment: Большое спасибо за развернутый ответ. И все же у меня вопрос. Можно ли сделать следующим образом: бульдозер и его дочерние компоненты должны создаваться в момент создания самого бульдозера. Просто таков сценарий. В данном случае считаю возможным нарушение принципа один агрегат - одна транзакция, но с оговорками. В репозитории каждого агрегата можно предусмотреть дополнительный метод, определяющий: используется ли агрегат другим бульдозером или нет.

Comment: При создании бульдозера на вход прикладного метода подавать id каждого дочернего агрегата. Затем в том же методе прикладной службы вызывать метод каждого репозитория для проверки использования дочернего агрегата другим бульдозером. Потом создавать бульдозер.Учитывая то, что в самой программе генерируемое дочернее оборудование при создании бульдозера будет выведено на экран только после создания самого бульдозера, считаю в данном случае проверку можно вообще не проводить. Если моя точка зрения ошибочна, то как лучше сделать?

Comment: @Eladei можно сделать. Более того, я дописал в конце - возможно получится сделать полностью по DDD используя вложенные транзакции. Тогда никто использовать дочерние агрегаты не сможет и можно будет делать меньше валидаций.

Comment: Вот только у меня вопрос) Можно ли считать транзакцией запуск метода прикладной службы? Просто под транзакцией я считал именно такой процесс.

Comment: @Eladei транзакционность СУБД обычно всегда имеется в виду в книгах по DDD. В целом - можете делать как вам угодно, но если ваша служба не будет обеспечивать реальной транзакционности, можно вполне получить несогласованные (а значит и невалидные) сущности, что плохо в целом для продукта.

Comment: А можно ли для решения вопроса использовать саги?

Comment: @Eladei я честно не сталкивался с термином "сага" в рамках DDD. Если речь про многошаговый бизнес-процесс - то почему нет, сборка бульдозера в это вполне впишется. Только тогда создание связанных агрегатов по моему отделяется от создания бульдозера.

Comment: Да. Я как раз и планировал создавать связанные агрегаты в отдельных прикладных службах. Суть в том, что прикладная служба создания бульдозера использует внутри себя прикладные службы создания связанных агрегатов.